# Typescript: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I have list of nestet array list, I am trying fiter based on the array value. When I filter getting error. I am using typescript with eslint.

```
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
```

But I checked the null/undefined value but still I am getting error.

```
interface User {
  id: string;
  username?: string;
}

function getList (user:User){
  if(user.username === undefined){
    return {};
  }
  let arrayData: string[][] = [];
  arrayData = [["abcd"],["efgh"],["xyz"],["abcd","xyz"]];
 //here i have differnt logic
  const filterData = arrayData.filter(list => list.includes(user.username));
  return filterData;
}

getList({id: "123", username: "xyz"});
```

When I use the `non-null assertion operator` it the error resolved but getting lint issue.

```
const filterData = arrayData.filter(list => list.includes(user.username!));
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: User Interface  already defined. so unable to "username?: string | undefined;"

Answer (score 7):

you are comparing the User `.username`, which is Optional, that means it's of type `string | undefined` to every `string` item in an array,

you can change the type of your array to: `arrayData: Array<Array<string|undefined>>` or you can just use `as` to treat it as a `string`, not `string|undefined`: i.e.: `list.includes(user.username as string)`

Comment: Just putting an exclamation at the end of the variable worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare username like this:

`username?: string | undefined;`

Comment: User Interface  already defined. so unable to "username?: string | undefined;"

Answer (score 1):

when you want to set a variable that already has a type | undefined, and the setter doesn't accept any type | undefined, you could use the ! at the end of the variable
for example:

for an interface like yours

> `interface User { id: int; username?: string }`

having a variable like

> `let userVariable = 'Terminator3000'`

you can do

> `user: User = { id: 123, username: userVariable! }`

! operator indicates that the value isn't undefined